# Jboss 5.0 EJB 3.0 Asynchronous Proxy

Tags: jboss, asynchronous, ejb

At  http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/EJB3/EJBtutorialfromJBossAsynchronouscall.htm
i've found an example showing how to call ejb methods in asynchronous fashion. Do you use asynchronous proxy in EJB 3.0 on Jboss AS and does it work as it should?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the version.  The latest version of the jboss ejb jars do NOT work per the linked example.
See: http://www.mastertheboss.com/en/jboss-server/219-ejb-31-tutorial.html
http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2010/03/simple-asynchronous-methods-in-ejb-31.html